# vue js isotope with packery layout-mode

Tags: vue.js, jquery-isotope

I'm using vue-isotope component from https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.Isotope

I'd like use layout-mode: 'packery' and I have installed the node module packery. So I have imported this module in my file vue but dosn't work, like this:

```
import isotope from 'vueisotope'
import 'packery
```

---

#### SOLUTION

I have found packery plugin at https://packery.metafizzy.co/
And it works fine! (without component)

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you forgot to add the component inside **components**

```
import isotope from 'vueisotope'
...
export default {
      /*   /!\ don't forget this /!\   */
      components: {
        isotope,
      }
      ...
}
```

Comment: No, there is it!